# Why grep command doesn't work within perl script

Tags: perl, unix, solaris

The following staement in perl throws an error

```
my $string =qx(ls grep test) ;
```

…where test is some file name to be searched...

But the following statements doen't through an error

```
my $string =qx(ls) ;
```

I am working in unix solaris machine

Comment: What error? Why do you think that `grep` is a command rather than an argument to `ls`?

Comment: I got it . Actually this is system dependent. Works for linux machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
my $string =qx(ls | grep test) ;
```